# Overriding the Celery Task Class to be able share variables between tasks

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celery-task

Am trying to implement a task where the global variables are shared between two different Celery tasks. For that, I have inherited task class and used property. As per celery documentation the base class will initialize when a new task is invoked. Do we have an approach where can reuse the object in between tasks? Can we override the run() method from Task? If we override the run method. How can we register the task ? with celery using Celery 5. X ? Tried Serializing object.. Any alternate approach would be appreciated.

```py
class handler(Task):

    def __init__(self):
        self.base_obj = ""

    @property
    def global_handler(self):
        return self.global_thread_handler

    @property
    def base_handler(self):
        return self.base_obj


    @app.task(base=handler)
    def test123():
        test123.base_handler = cls1()


    @app.task(base=handler)
    def test456():
        test456.base_handler.method()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Celery` is using multiple processes to be able run tasks asynchronous. No matter what Task class you will use it will be visible only inside a worker. If you want to share variables between processes you have to use `multiprocessing` [specific objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Queue) to be able share value outside single process.:

```py
from celery import Celery, Task
from multiprocessing import Queue

BROKER_URL = 'sqla+sqlite:///celery.db'

app = Celery(
    'tasks',
    broker='sqla+sqlite:///celery.db',
    backend='db+sqlite:///celery_results.db'
)

q = Queue()

@app.task
def set_var(val: str):
    # put is appending new value to Queue every time when we call set_var
    q.put(val)
    print(f'Global variable has been changed to {val}')


@app.task
def get_var():
    if not q.empty():
        # get is popping first value from Queue if Queue is not empty
        val = q.get()
        print(f'Global variable is {val}')
        return val
    else:
        print('Global variable is EMPTY')
```

So, if we run:

```py
>>> from tasks import set_var, get_var
>>> get_var.delay()
<AsyncResult: 387d02a2-a993-4ea4-9dc6-37b4a6657f92>
>>> set_var.delay('NEW VALUE')
<AsyncResult: 8b02519f-cd87-4e88-9270-2c621f84b14e>
>>> get_var.delay()
<AsyncResult: 828047b1-5f3a-4980-b922-224d0cfb628d>
```

The logs will be like:

```
[2023-03-25 20:38:29,670: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.get_var[387d02a2-a993-4ea4-9dc6-37b4a6657f92] received
[2023-03-25 20:38:29,674: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Global variable is EMPTY
[2023-03-25 20:38:29,723: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task tasks.get_var[387d02a2-a993-4ea4-9dc6-37b4a6657f92] succeeded in 0.049737373999960255s: None
[2023-03-25 20:38:45,801: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.set_var[8b02519f-cd87-4e88-9270-2c621f84b14e] received
[2023-03-25 20:38:45,802: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Global variable has been changed to NEW VALUE
[2023-03-25 20:38:45,822: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task tasks.set_var[8b02519f-cd87-4e88-9270-2c621f84b14e] succeeded in 0.02061020500059385s: None
[2023-03-25 20:38:49,846: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.get_var[828047b1-5f3a-4980-b922-224d0cfb628d] received
[2023-03-25 20:38:49,848: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] Global variable is NEW VALUE
[2023-03-25 20:38:49,870: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task tasks.get_var[828047b1-5f3a-4980-b922-224d0cfb628d] succeeded in 0.022652251000181423s: 'NEW VALUE'
```

As you can see `ForkPoolWorker-3` is able to read value that was set inside `ForkPoolWorker-2`

You have to be careful with shared variables because of locks and concurrency problems. I recommend to simply use a DB for storing values that should be accessible from different sources

Answer (score -1):

Registering a task in Celery can be simply done using something like this:

```py
# my_app/tasks.py
import celery
from my_app.celery import app

class MyTask(celery.Task):
    def run(self):
        [...]

MyTask = app.register_task(MyTask())
```

I think there's no way you can reuse the objects within tasks. Can someone correct me on this?